# django commands ' py manage.py runserver / makemigrations / migrate' not working as expected

Tags: python, django

Hi there I wanted to run a project ive been working on but on running py manage.py runserver i got unfamilliar output in the command line instead of the usual output showing that the development server is running I have no clue whatsoever has caused this
[image]

Its the same thing if i run makemigrations or migrate any pointers

Comment: Please add tracebacks in a text form. It makes us easier to research.

Comment: they are sooo many that is why i took a screenshot

Comment: just curious, why you are using `pipenv` ? the defacto python virtual environment is `venv` and it's the recommended way.

Comment: well I prefer it since i do not have to manually add every package I install to a requirements.txt file, using pipenv automates this by adding every package I install to a pipfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've most likely enabled `DEBUG` level for autoreload logging, change it to `INFO` in settings.py:

```py
LOGGING = {
  ...
  'loggers': {
    'django.utils.autoreload': {
      'level': 'INFO',
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct I had adjusted settings for logging so as to trace errors on my production server and was still using the same setting for my development server thanks @GProst